# How to use pre-trained BERT model for next sentence labeling?

Tags: tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, nlp

I”m new to AI and NLP. 
I want to check how bert works. 
I use BERT pre-trained model:
https://github.com/google-research/bert

I ran extract_features.py example , described in extract features paragraph in readme.md. 
I  got vectors, as output.

Guys, how to transform result, i got in extract_features.py, to get next/ not next label?

I want to run bert to check whether two sentences are related, and see result.

Thanks!

Comment: in Jay's blog:  http://jalammar.github.io/illustrated-bert/ he mentions, "Which vector works best as a contextualized embedding? I would think it depends on the task. The paper examines six choices (Compared to the fine-tuned model which achieved a score of 96.4):" but how do we grab the outputs at each encoder layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use weights, what was used nor next sentence trainings, and logits from there. So, to use Bert for nextSentence input two sentences in a format used for training:

```py
def convert_single_example(ex_index, example, label_list, max_seq_length,
                           tokenizer):
    """Converts a single `InputExample` into a single `InputFeatures`."""
    label_map = {}
    for (i, label) in enumerate(label_list):
        label_map[label] = i

    tokens_a = tokenizer.tokenize(example.text_a)
    tokens_b = None
    if example.text_b:
        tokens_b = tokenizer.tokenize(example.text_b)

    if tokens_b:
        # Modifies `tokens_a` and `tokens_b` in place so that the total
        # length is less than the specified length.
        # Account for [CLS], [SEP], [SEP] with "- 3"
        _truncate_seq_pair(tokens_a, tokens_b, max_seq_length - 3)
    else:
        # Account for [CLS] and [SEP] with "- 2"
        if len(tokens_a) > max_seq_length - 2:
            tokens_a = tokens_a[0:(max_seq_length - 2)]

    # The convention in BERT is:
    # (a) For sequence pairs:
    #  tokens:   [CLS] is this jack ##son ##ville ? [SEP] no it is not . [SEP]
    #  type_ids: 0     0  0    0    0     0       0 0     1  1  1  1   1 1
    # (b) For single sequences:
    #  tokens:   [CLS] the dog is hairy . [SEP]
    #  type_ids: 0     0   0   0  0     0 0
    #
    # Where "type_ids" are used to indicate whether this is the first
    # sequence or the second sequence. The embedding vectors for `type=0` and
    # `type=1` were learned during pre-training and are added to the wordpiece
    # embedding vector (and position vector). This is not *strictly* necessary
    # since the [SEP] token unambiguously separates the sequences, but it makes
    # it easier for the model to learn the concept of sequences.
    #
    # For classification tasks, the first vector (corresponding to [CLS]) is
    # used as as the "sentence vector". Note that this only makes sense because
    # the entire model is fine-tuned.
    tokens = []
    segment_ids = []
    tokens.append("[CLS]")
    segment_ids.append(0)
    for token in tokens_a:
        tokens.append(token)
        segment_ids.append(0)
    tokens.append("[SEP]")
    segment_ids.append(0)

    if tokens_b:
        for token in tokens_b:
            tokens.append(token)
            segment_ids.append(1)
        tokens.append("[SEP]")
        segment_ids.append(1)

    input_ids = tokenizer.convert_tokens_to_ids(tokens)

    # The mask has 1 for real tokens and 0 for padding tokens. Only real
    # tokens are attended to.
    input_mask = [1] * len(input_ids)

    # Zero-pad up to the sequence length.
    while len(input_ids) < max_seq_length:
        input_ids.append(0)
        input_mask.append(0)
        segment_ids.append(0)

    assert len(input_ids) == max_seq_length
    assert len(input_mask) == max_seq_length
    assert len(segment_ids) == max_seq_length

    label_id = label_map[example.label]
    if ex_index < 5:
        tf.logging.info("*** Example ***")
        tf.logging.info("guid: %s" % (example.guid))
        tf.logging.info("tokens: %s" % " ".join(
            [tokenization.printable_text(x) for x in tokens]))
        tf.logging.info("input_ids: %s" % " ".join([str(x) for x in input_ids]))
        tf.logging.info("input_mask: %s" % " ".join([str(x) for x in input_mask]))
        tf.logging.info("segment_ids: %s" % " ".join([str(x) for x in segment_ids]))
        tf.logging.info("label: %s (id = %d)" % (example.label, label_id))

    feature = InputFeatures(
        input_ids=input_ids,
        input_mask=input_mask,
        segment_ids=segment_ids,
        label_id=label_id)
    return feature
```

And then extend Bert model with next code

```py
def create_model(bert_config, is_training, input_ids, input_mask, segment_ids,
                 labels, num_labels, use_one_hot_embeddings):
    """Creates a classification model."""
    model = modeling.BertModel(
        config=bert_config,
        is_training=is_training,
        input_ids=input_ids,
        input_mask=input_mask,
        token_type_ids=segment_ids,
        use_one_hot_embeddings=use_one_hot_embeddings)

    # In the demo, we are doing a simple classification task on the entire
    # segment.
    #
    # If you want to use the token-level output, use model.get_sequence_output()
    # instead.
    output_layer = model.get_pooled_output()

    hidden_size = output_layer.shape[-1].value

    with tf.variable_scope("cls/seq_relationship"):
        output_weights = tf.get_variable(
            "output_weights", [num_labels, hidden_size])

        output_bias = tf.get_variable(
            "output_bias", [num_labels])

    with tf.variable_scope("loss"):
        if is_training:
            # I.e., 0.1 dropout
            output_layer = tf.nn.dropout(output_layer, keep_prob=0.9)

        logits = tf.matmul(output_layer, output_weights, transpose_b=True)
        logits = tf.nn.bias_add(logits, output_bias)
        probabilities = tf.nn.softmax(logits, axis=-1)
        log_probs = tf.nn.log_softmax(logits, axis=-1)

        one_hot_labels = tf.one_hot(labels, depth=num_labels, dtype=tf.float32)

        per_example_loss = -tf.reduce_sum(one_hot_labels * log_probs, axis=-1)
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(per_example_loss)

        return (loss, per_example_loss, logits, probabilities)
```

probabilities - is what you need, its nextSentence preditions

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you can do it in tensorflow. But in the pythorch implementation by hugging face https://github.com/huggingface/pytorch-pretrained-BERT/blob/master/pytorch_pretrained_bert/modeling.py#L854 there is a model BertForNextSentencePrediction.

Comment: No, its possible since bert model was trained for this purpose

Comment: Yes you are right. From here https://github.com/google-research/bert/blob/master/run_pretraining.py you can use the  get_next_sentence_output function